# Casting an Anonymous type to a known type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that contains the following Linq to SQL code:

```
    public List<L2SBusinessEntities.Report.MesReport> GetListForReportTree(MESProductionDatabase database)
    {
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[1];
    var results =
        from report in database.MesReport
        select new { report.MesReportID, 
            report.ParentID, 
            report.ReportTitle, 
            report.ReportName, 
            report.DatabaseServer, 
            report.DatabaseName, 
            report.Login, 
            ReportFile = byteArray };

    return (List<L2SBusinessEntities.Report.MesReport>)results;
    }
```

I'm getting an unable to cast error in trying to cast 'results' to the type shown in the return statement. Should I be able to do this? An L2SBusinessEntities.Report.MesReport entity looks as follows:

```
int MesReportID
int ParentID
string ReportTitle
string ReportName
string DatabaseServer
string DatabaseName
string Login
byte[] ReportFile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method does not need casting. You can use the following code to return List of your objects:

```
public List<L2SBusinessEntities.Report.MesReport> GetListForReportTree(MESProductionDatabase database)
        {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[1];
        var results = (
            from report in database.MesReport
            select new L2SBusinessEntities.Report.MesReport { 
                MesReportID = report.MesReportID, 
                ParentID = report.ParentID, 
                ReportTitle = report.ReportTitle, 
                ReportName = report.ReportName, 
                DatabaseServer = report.DatabaseServer, 
                DatabaseName = report.DatabaseName, 
                Login = report.Login, 
                ReportFile = byteArray }).ToList();

        return results;
        }
```

update -------------

another option for your query:

```
public List<L2SBusinessEntities.Report.MesReport> GetListForReportTree(MESProductionDatabase database)
        {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[1];
        var results = (
            from report in database.MesReport
            select new { 
                MesReportID = report.MesReportID, 
                ParentID = report.ParentID, 
                ReportTitle = report.ReportTitle, 
                ReportName = report.ReportName, 
                DatabaseServer = report.DatabaseServer, 
                DatabaseName = report.DatabaseName, 
                Login = report.Login, 
                ReportFile = byteArray })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(c => new L2SBusinessEntities.Report.MesReport{ 
                MesReportID = c.MesReportID, 
                ParentID = c.ParentID, 
                ReportTitle = c.ReportTitle, 
                ReportName = c.ReportName, 
                DatabaseServer = c.DatabaseServer, 
                DatabaseName = c.DatabaseName, 
                Login = c.Login, 
                ReportFile = c.ReportFile }).ToList();

        return results;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not work. It compiles fine, but when I run it, I get an error saying, "Explicit construction of entity type L2SBusinessEntities.Report.MesReport in query is not allowed".

Comment: Try my updated example, please. It seems that L2SBusinessEntities.Report.MesReport is entity class. You can retrieve them using queries, but you can't create entities as part of a query.

Comment: I just thought, is your database.MesReport contains L2SBusinessEntities.Report.MesReport entites? in this case you can simply write: var results = (from report in database.MesReport select report).ToList();

Comment: `var results = database.MesReport.ToList();`, _please_

Comment: Yes I could certainly do what you describe (or SLaks) but the point is that I don't want the contents of the ReportFile column included. This is a VarBinary column and I don't need or want it for this query. This is why I'm providing my own value for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you cannot cast like that.  You could add a constructor to your MesReport class that has params in the same order you listed to do this:

```
var results =
        from report in database.MesReport
        select new L2SBusinessEntities.Report.MesReport(report.MesReportID, 
            report.ParentID, 
            report.ReportTitle, 
            report.ReportName, 
            report.DatabaseServer, 
            report.DatabaseName, 
            report.Login, 
            ReportFile = byteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to something like:

```
....your code through "from report in database.MesReport" here
select new L2SBusinessEntities.Report.MesReport() {
  report.ParentID,   
  report.ReportTitle,   
  report.ReportName,   
  report.DatabaseServer,   
  report.DatabaseName,   
  report.Login,   
  ReportFile = byteArray 
};
```

If you wrap all of that in parens, you can then even call `.ToList()` on the LINQ query itself so you don't have to cast it when you return it.